# Generating c++ classes without a precompiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, code-generation

One of our projects involves generating boilerplate code for classes.

For example, given a text file with multiple definitions like:

```
STRUCT Foo
{
    int i;
    float f;
    string s;
}
```

a Perl script will create a header file with multiple declarations like:

```
struct Type_Foo : BaseType
{
    int i;
    float f;
    string s;

    Generated_Foo();
    void clear();
    bool equals(Generated_Foo const&) const;
    string const* toTraceString() const;
    string const* toXmlString() const;
    string const* toJsonString() const;
    bool fromXmlString(char const*);
    bool fromJsonString(char const*);
};
```

and a corresponding cpp file with the implementations.

My question is:

Is it possible to achieve a similar result (modulo syntax differences) without the precompiler stage?

Thank you!

Comment: Um, I think it's impossible to do it perfectly. Anyway, `struct Type_Foo : BaseType`? Do you intend private inheritance?

Comment: Look up code generators.  There are some applications that can convert UML drawings into C++ classes.

Comment: @ikh `struct`s inherit publicly by default, one of the two differences between classes and structs in C++. AlexO: You'll need some kind of precompilation stage, be it Perl scripts or something else. Why are you looking to change what you have right now? Knowing the reason might help someone suggest a tool that's capable of doing what you're looking for.

Comment: > Why are you looking to change what you have right now?
I'm not.  I'm just curious if this _can_ be done within the language

Comment: There's no simple way.  So it will depend on how much of a stretch in input syntax, and syntax of using the "generated" type, you'll tolerate.

Answer (score 1):

[Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) can do this, just by (ab)using the C/C++ preprocessor.  It could look something like this.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>

#define STRUCT_MEMBER(r, data, elem) elem;

#define STRUCT(structname, seq) \
    struct Type_ ## structname : BaseType { \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(STRUCT_MEMBER, _, seq) \
        Generated_ ## structname(); \
        void clear(); \
        bool equals(Generated_Foo const&) const; \
        string const* toTraceString() const; \
        string const* toXmlString() const; \
        string const* toJsonString() const; \
        bool fromXmlString(char const*); \
        bool fromJsonString(char const*); \
    }

STRUCT(Foo, (int i)(float f)(string s));
```

Having worked with Boost.Preprocessor, my opinion is that, although it's very cool and can be useful to do everything within C++, it can quickly get complicated for nontrivial uses.  If you already have a good, working external code generator (like your Perl scripts), there's nothing wrong with continuing to use it.